# .htaccess - string in url without subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The URL is the following `http://local.example.com/features.html` and what I need is to add a text like "country" `http://local.example.com/us/feature.html` but with the code I have when I click on the URL the site shows a 404 error

This is only visual without creating a US sub-folder.

The code...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} local.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} location=us [NC] --> CHECK COOKIE FOR ACTION
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/us/  --> EXCLUDE US FOR REDIRECT LOOP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/ --> EXCLUDE BLOG FOLDER WITH WORDPRESS
RewriteRule ^(.*)!\.(css|js|png|jpg)$ http://local.example.com/us/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: "without creating a US sub-folder." - Ah, just noticed this after posting my answer. If the `/us` subfolder does not actually exist then how is a request for `http://local.example.com/us/feature.html` expected to resolve? What is the URL you are actually linking to in the HTML source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)!\.(css|js|png|jpg)$ http://local.example.com/us/$1 [R=302,L]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* will not match the requested URL (because of the erroneous `!`) so this directive won't actually do anything. From this I also assume you are wanting to exclude requests for CSS, JS, `.png` and `.jpg` files? You also have a condition that excludes requests made to a `/blog/` subdirectory, however, you've not mentioned this in your question?

You also reference a cookie in the code? However, you've not mentioned this in your question and this won't work in its current state (since it won't be present on initial requests), so I'll ignore this for now.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpg)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteRule !^us/ /us%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

The above states, given a request for `/foo/bar`...

1. For any request that does not start with `/us/`
2. And is for the `Host` `local.example.com`
3. And is *not* for a URL that ends with either `.css`, `.js`, `.png` or `.jpg`
4. And does not start with `/blog/`
5. Then 302 (temporary) redirect to `/us/foo/bar`

Unless you have multiple hosts on this account, you don't need to explicitly check the `Host` header as part of the rule?

Comment: Aha, my mistake for not mentioning that.
Your code works perfectly, but my idea (if possible, of course) is not to do a redirection and just add the US at a visual level.